# Redshift query between date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm quite new to Redshift SQL.

```
    select *  from myredshift_tbl 
    where local_date between \'2016-01-01\' and \'2017-02-01\';
```

But got this error:

[amazon][500310] invalid  operation  syntax error at  or near "\". I believe Redshift use single quote and I need to escape single quote.

Comment: Delete the backslash...

Comment: The backslashes are unnecessary.  Remove them.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if you are satisfied with it. It will help other users who find this question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If the column `local_date` is in date format, use:

```
select *  from myredshift_tbl 
    where local_date between '2016-01-01' and '2017-02-01';
```

If the column `local_date` is timestamp:

```
select *  from myredshift_tbl 
        where local_date between '2016-01-01 00:00:00' and '2017-02-01 23:59:59';
```

Comment: What happens if the lower and upper bound are reversed?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM schemaName.TableName WHERE datetime > '2017-02-09 
00:00:00' AND datetime < '2017-06-09 00:00:00';
```

The above query Works with Redshift to fetch all the entries in a table.

**NOTE:** The table I applied the query on had column/field 'datetime' of type 'timestamp'.

I tested this query on Redshift with the help of Workbench J.